# Metro style app login to SharePoint

Tags: 2013, authentication, login, windows-8

I have a metro style app based on the metro style web browser (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Metro-Style-Web-Browser-ecde9a6d)

In this browser I navigate to a page on a SharePoint site: http://mySharepointServer.com/sites/pages/page.aspx

The problem is that you have to login to have access to SharePoint. In other browsers you will get a pop-up prompting you to login but not with the metro style web browser. I just get a blank page.

How can I login to SharePoint before navigating to the SharePoint site so you are already logged in automatically?

Comment: You wouldn't really use REST or web services to login. That is actually a part of HTTP. Granted you can add authentication to REST and web services HTTP calls, but that is not the same as generating and saving a session for your browser. In one case you are using JavaScript as the client, but in your case you are using your custom browser as the client. I think this is probably a more general programming question than a SharePoint question.

Comment: I think this question is related to what you're trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181821/providing-domain-user-credentials-to-webview-control